# How to promote research commercialization?

Tags: research-process

What efforts have there been to promote research commercialization (e.g. connecting researchers with investors interested in commercializing the researchers' research) and how are these done?

Comment: Where? In the United States, there are federal laws related to "technology transfer" from publicly funded researchers to industry. I am sure this will vary widely between countries, regions, and individual universities.

Comment: I think this is a very interesting subject. I'm presently only vaguely aware of how some institutions have special efforts for this where they actively encourage commercial "spin-offs" (along with licensing and royalties paid to the institution in the future if the company gets off the ground). I'm also aware that there are special grants and initiatives in various systems that encourage it. One I saw recently offered up to $100,000 for one year to develop an idea from the "business plan" stage into something that could potentially be ready to seek outside investment. Would love to know more.

Comment: Note: the grant I saw was very specific, I believe focusing on a business/technology concept based around renewable energy.

Comment: Hi Tim, may I ask as to how these laws will affect the process of research commercialization?

Comment: Hi Brian, may I know as to what this grant is?

Comment: I feel this question very broad. Not only the topic itself, but what is the angle? Which country/continent? Are you asking about federal policy, grants, institutional efforts, successful examples of individual efforts, local government supports, industrial efforts? What industry? Bio, chem, pharma or computational science works very-very different ways.

Answer (score 4):

In the US, at least, there are *lots* of different mechanisms intended to try to facilitate commercialization.  The major players are:

- Universities, who want to make money by licensing patents
- Entrepreneurs and venture capital groups, who see new technology as  one of the best sources of profitable market disruption.
- Large established companies, who want to acquire new technology in order to prevent their markets from being disrupted and to disrupt their competitors.
- Local, state, and national governments, who see tech transfer as a both a major economic benefit and an important justification for investing public money in research.

A few of the many significant mechanisms:

- Every research university has some form of Technology Transfer Office, whose job is to get researchers and business people introduced and help them figure out opportunities for commercialization.  Many universities also have "sabbatical for a startup" programs for their faculty, official or otherwise.
- Regional associations, like the [Massachusetts Association of Technology Transfer Offices](http://www.masstechtransfer.org/) or the [Northwest Future Energy Conferences](http://www.futureenergyconference.com/) do the same thing on a larger scale.
- [SBIR/STTR](http://www.sbir.gov/) programs are a whole family of programs where significant amounts of government grant money is allocated specifically to commercialization of new technology by startups and other small businesses.  Some small businesses effectively set themselves up as independent research institutes with this money.
- Within subfields, there are often specific joint industry/academia programs specifically designed to facilitate technology transfer.  For example the [Semiconductor Research Corporation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiconductor_Research_Corporation) is designed to serve as an industry/academia bridge in, well, semiconductor research.  Another example is [SynBERC](http://synberc.org/), a long-term NSF project in synthetic biology which includes a highly successful program for industry involvement at all scales.

The interface between academia and industry, in the US at least, is much more intense and complicated than many realize.  You just have to go looking for connections into it.